# How can I select all untagged photos in Shotwell?

Tags: shotwell, tagging, tag, functions

I would like to be able, to select all untagged and tagged photos in [Shotwell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell) separately, so that I may tag and re-tag them.

- How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and found
[this in a bug report against shotwell](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shotwell/+bug/881582)

> Eric Gregory (eric-yorba) wrote on 2011-10-25:     #2
>
> May not be so obvious, but you can list all untagged photos.
>
> Create a new saved search (ctrl+s) and set the criteria to "Tag" "is not set." Then click OK.
>
> Your new saved search will show all untagged photos.

Answer (score 0):

Shotwell Organizing Photos:  [Tagging photos](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/tag.html) or [Search Function](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/search.html) or [Shotwell Manual Help](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/)

- I suggest that you use the search function, to filter images/photos first, then make a selection of them all, by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> key-shorcut. Finally start tagging.